# SQL LOOP RESULT TO ONE TABLE

Tags: loops, t-sql, temp-tables

I have a SQL query and results as below

How to output the results to a table?

I tried insert into a temp table,

but only shows 1 record for each results.

Please find the code and results picture below

```
DECLARE @SUPID nvarchar(40);
DECLARE @MY_CURSOR CURSOR; --LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY

Begin
set @MY_CURSOR = CURSOR FOR Select oid [AllSUPID] from JHgrDesignSupport

open @MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM @MY_CURSOR INTO @SUPID

DECLARE @Output TABLE (
[PipeRun] nvarchar(50),
        SUP nvarchar(50));
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin

select n1.ItemName [PipeRun]
, @SUPID [SUP] 

from ((SELECT OID from JRange JRX Where OID in  (Select OID from JRtePipeStraightPathFeat)
and not ((JRX.xmin>  
(select sr.xmax from 
(select js.oid, jr.xmax, jr.xmin, jr.ymax, jr.ymin, jr.zmax, jr.zmin from JHgrDesignSupport js
join JRange jr on jr.oid = js.oid) as sr where sr.oid = @SUPID)
or xmax <(select sr.xmin from 
(select js.oid, jr.xmax, jr.xmin, jr.ymax, jr.ymin, jr.zmax, jr.zmin from JHgrDesignSupport js
join JRange jr on jr.oid = js.oid) as sr where sr.oid = @SUPID))
or
(JRX.ymin>  
(select sr.ymax from 
(select js.oid, jr.xmax, jr.xmin, jr.ymax, jr.ymin, jr.zmax, jr.zmin from JHgrDesignSupport js
join JRange jr on jr.oid = js.oid) as sr where sr.oid = @SUPID)
or ymax <(select sr.ymin from 
(select js.oid, jr.xmax, jr.xmin, jr.ymax, jr.ymin, jr.zmax, jr.zmin from JHgrDesignSupport js
join JRange jr on jr.oid = js.oid) as sr where sr.oid = @SUPID))
or 
(JRX.zmin>  
(select (sr.zmax) from 
(select js.oid, jr.xmax, jr.xmin, jr.ymax, jr.ymin, jr.zmax, jr.zmin from JHgrDesignSupport js
join JRange jr on jr.oid = js.oid) as sr where sr.oid = @SUPID)
or zmax <(select sr.zmin from 
(select js.oid, jr.xmax, jr.xmin, jr.ymax, jr.ymin, jr.zmax, jr.zmin from JHgrDesignSupport js
join JRange jr on jr.oid = js.oid) as sr where sr.oid = @SUPID)))
) as t1
join XPathSpecification x1 on x1.oidDestination = t1.oid
join JNamedItem n1 on n1.oid = x1.oidOrigin)

FETCH NEXT FROM @MY_CURSOR INTO @SUPID
END;
    CLOSE @MY_CURSOR;   
END;
```

results

[image]